# Sorting by multiple fields SearchCursor ArcGIS 10.6

Tags: arcpy, cursor, sorting

I want to define the values of first row in a sorted table with search cursor.
My code is working without sorting, but I don't know how can I integrate into sorting.
I would like to see only the values of first row ("src_ORIG_FID","nbr_ORIG_FID"), with the smallest area and longer length. I want to sort rows first by "src_Shape_Area" Ascending, then by LENGTH Descending. After sorting, if the "if statement" is done, the first good row is needed.

[image]

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tablaL,["src_ORIG_FID","nbr_ORIG_FID","src_Shape_Area","LENGTH","SUM"],"","","src_Shape_Area A;LENGTH D") as nCursor:
    for row in nCursor:
        if row [4]<50000.00 and row[3]> 0: #if it is TRUE
            for row in nCursor:
                orig1 = row[0] #only first row value is needed
                orig2 = row[1]
                break
        else:   
            break
```

Comment: The documented syntax looks different from what you are providing (`sql_clause` is a two-element list). It also includes the text `Note:
DISTINCT, ORDER BY, and ALL are only supported when working with databases.`

Comment: How many rows are there in your table?

Comment: More than 100 rows, and proximately 50% is out of "if statement".

Comment: Yes, it is in file geodatabase.  I want to sorting, but the "if statement" is not come true go further the second row,etc... Vince what is your recomendation to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have ~100 rows you can list all values, and then [sort](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp) using python:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb\my_sample'

fields = ['OBJECTID', 'KKOD', 'Shape_Length', 'Shape_Area']

data = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) if row[2]>0 and row[3]<50000] #List all rows meeting the if conditions

data.sort(key=lambda x: (x[2], -x[3])) #Sort by field index 2 and 3 (-3 for descending sort)
orig1, orig2 = data[0][:2] #Fetch first and second value of the first row in the sorted list of tuples
```